# Show that $(x_n)$ is cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying the following condition:

For each
$\epsilon>0$ there exist a positive integer $N$ such that $|x_n-x_N|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Show that $(x_n)$ is cauchy sequence.

$\underline{Attempt}$

By given definition,

Let $\epsilon>0$, then exist a positive integer $N$ such that $|x_n-x_N|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $n>N$

Take any $m \in \mathbb{N}$  s.t $m>n$ follows that

$|x_m-x_N|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $n>N$,

$$|x_m-x_n|=|x_m-x_N-(x_n-x_N)|<|x_n-x_N|+|x_m-x_N|<\epsilon$$whenever $m>n>N$,

thus $(x_n)$ is cauchy sequence

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: Since it appears that you invoked the triangle inequality, I think it would be more precise to say $|x_m-x_N-(x_n-x_N)| \leq |x_n-x_N| + |x_m-x_N|$, with the emphasis on the $\leq$ sign as opposed to the traditional $<$ sign

Comment: @SunRoad2 Thank you I forgot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it can be simplified a bit. You have that for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|x_n-x_N|<\varepsilon/2$. From there, let $n,m\geq N$. Then $$|x_n-x_m|=|x_n-x_N+x_N-x_m|\leq|x_n-x_N|+|x_m-x_N|$$Because $n,m\geq N$, then you are done, as $|x_n-x_N|,|x_m-x_N|<\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: Thank you. your answer is better than mine.

Comment: @DARK you're welcome. it was your proof that did all of the work. i just suggested a simplification. nice job :-)